# How build a chart plot with a text column vs number column in matplotlib from a file.txt?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, charts, textlabel

I'm new in python and now I'm trying to do a chart plot in matplotlib from a file with a lot of data that have one number column and a text column in this format:

```
34 Louis Mathews Sullivan
58 Frederick Milton2
 1 Mario Cruz MuÃ±oz
```

I would like to have a plot like this

[image]

and like this:

[image]

Considering that is not data frame, the column of name give me some problems.
Can you help me and support about this? Thanks

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately I can't answer

Comment: *Considering that is not data frame*, if this is not a dataframe, why did you say you have two columns?

Comment: Hi Quang Hoang, because I wanted to say that names must be considerate as a one column. I don't have idea how convert this in a data frame and then plot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try reading this to a dataframe, split it and plot:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv', sep='\t', header=None)

df = df[0].str.extract('^([\d]+)\s+(.+)')
df.columns=['number', 'name']
df['number'] = df['number'].astype(float)
df.plot.bar(x='name', y='number')
```

Output (for the sample data):

[image]

If you want horizontal bar, use `plot.barh` instead:

```
df.plot.barh(x='name', y='number')
```

And you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Quang Hoang. Greetings!